# Regular Expression rxrepl - why basic command not working in this software (compare to notepad++)

Tags: regex, pcre

What's wrong with this great tool to get the right result? 
[Regular Expression Search and Replace Command Line Tool](https://sites.google.com/site/regexreplace/)

Basic reg command not working, I don't know why? 
(I did try i notepad++ and everythings works fine)

```
^(Login:.+\R).+\R.+(?:\R|\z)
```

replace with

```
\1
```

before:

```
Login: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Login: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
```

after:

```
Login: xxxx
Login: xxxx
```

then I put this code to software **rxrepl**

```
rxrepl.exe -f C:\regex\test.txt -o C:\regex\done\test.txt -s "^(Login:.+\R).+\R.+(?:\R|\z)" -r "\1"
```

and this is my results

```
Login: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
Login: xxxx
Lng: Java:version- xxxx
Code: xxx
```

why the program does not execute the command?

Comment: Pass `-m file` option and use `(?m)^(Login:.+\R).+\R.+(?:\R|\z)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so it should be like this: rxrepl.exe -m file -f C:\regex\test.txt -o C:\regex\done\test.txt -s "(?m)^(Login:.+\R).+\R.+(?:\R|\z)" -r "\1   ???

Comment: You can also do that directly in Perl, e.g. `perl -0777 -pE "s/^(Login:.+\R).+\R.+(?:\R|\z)/$1/mg" test.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do You speak polish? :) ja również! I did try and don't work, still the same result.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Right now i can't use Perl :( just regex

Comment: Tak, mówię po polsku, ale tu trzeba pisać po angielsku. Sorry, it looks like the problem is tool specific. It makes sense to close this question as off-topic here and ask the tool developer for help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so what is the better tool to change a lot of files with one regex command?

Comment: @Tom Why not use Notepad++ since you are already good at it? CTRL+H and then choose *Find in Files* tab, there is *Replace in Files* option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, Notepad++ is great tool, but i need to use via CMD and really don't know if it is possible to use notepad++ in this way

Comment: If you are on Windows, why aren't you using Powershell? It has all you need then.

Comment: This questions pertains to PCRE, not Perl. Tags fixed.